# Why is the output of child_process.execSync empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, command-line

I am writing a simple script with Node.JS and I'd like to obtain the history of the previous command ran in the current session of the terminal.

I am using the function [child_process.execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) but it is not working as expected.

This is an example that I have found online and it works OK:

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
var out = execSync('ls');
console.log(out);
process.stdout.write(out);
```

This is the output:

```
<Buffer 4c 49 43 45 4e 53 45 0a 52 45 41 44 4d 45 2e 6d 64 0a 69 6e 64 65 78 2e 6a 73 0a 6f 62 73 6f 6c 65 74 65 2e 6a 73 0a 70 61 63 6b 61 67 65 2e 6a 73 6f ... >
LICENSE
README.md
index.js
package.json
test.txt
```

However, I get an empty string if I try to run **history** (I am currently using zsh)

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
var out = execSync('history');
console.log(out);
process.stdout.write(out);
```

This is the output:

```
<Buffer >
```

Is this because the commands are actually started in a different environment?

I have tried to use a command that does not exist and I see this the error:

```
/bin/sh: hist: command not found
child_process.js:1382
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Command failed: hist
/bin/sh: hist: command not found
```

It looks like it is using /bin/sh and I think it could be connected to my error...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`history` is [builtin command](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html), you have to call `zsh` executable to with command to get desired result([how to call history from shell scipt](https://superuser.com/questions/527299/how-to-call-history-fc-from-a-zsh-script))

```
var out = execSync("zsh -c 'export HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history; fc -R; fc -l 20'");
```

But you could also just read `~/.zsh_history` file and parse it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! What if I don't know in advance which shell is currently used? Is there a way to make this independent from zsh?